# Как посчитать время потраченное на выполнение задания?

Tags: java, android, время, счетчики

Пишу маленькое приложение на Android на Java. У меня пользователи в одном активити проходят тест и, по завершению теста, открывается следующее активити, в которое передается итоговая инфа по прохождению теста. Так вот, одно из полей - это потраченное время на задание... я пробую считать время хронометром, но он в миллисекундах считает и потом форматировать через различные проверки в формат 00:00 (02 : 34), очень костыльно получается... Я уверен, что есть более изящное решение...

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его "верным" нажав галочку слева от его тела.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В начале задания сохраняйте текущее время в `long` переменную:

   ```
   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ```
2. После окончания получайте разницу:

   ```
   long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
   ```
3. Берём класс `Calendar` и присваиваем ему полученное значение:

   ```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTimeInMillis( totalTime );
   ```
4. Получаем минуты/секунды (без нулей в начале):

   ```
   int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
   ```

или в форматированном виде с помощью класса `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Зачем создавать новый объект, если есть время выполнения в секундах?  Его обычной арифметикой можно быстро и просто преобразовать в любую удобную форму.

Comment: @LEQADA, можно, но зачем, если есть `SimpleDateFormat`?.. Без него надо будет руками нули в начале добавлять и всё такое..

Comment: А, я как-то пропустил ту часть, где ТС называет мой способ кастыльным :)

Comment: @LEQADA, а я вот сейчас обнаружил, что больше не вижу удалённых ответов((( Чёртов выход из беты)))

Comment: На 10К начнёте. Мало осталось ;)

Comment: @LEQADA, ну, не в этом году всё же, согласно среднему заработку репы)

Comment: Спасибо)) заработало  !!                                                               SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));   вот это использовал, в первом варианте без нулей выводит ( 0:0 ).

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, пожалуйста) Первый вариант и не должен был сработать. Это просто пример пользования класса `Calendar`. =)